# Configure nginx using reverse_proxy and wordgpress for subdirectory /blog

Tags: wordpress, nginx, content-management-system

I wish to configure nginx with a reverse_proxy (`proxy_pass`) that routes into my app in `localhost:3000` and the `location` `/blog` it routes to wordpress.

The config file I have is:

```
server {

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    #begin ssl_certificates
    .....
    #end ssl_certificates

        server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/example.com; #WP files are in /var/www/example.com/blog
        index index.php;

        location /blog {
                alias /var/www/example.com/blog; #the WP files are in /var/www/example.com/blog also tried /var/www/example.com
                index index.php;

                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
                
                location ~ \.php$ { 
                       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust the version based on your PHP-FPM version
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {

        listen 80;

        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

}
```

When I go to path `https://example.com/blog` it shows a 404.

Other configs I tried is moving the WP files to `/var/www/example.com`, nevertheless I don't think this is the issue because is actually not redirecting to the static files.

I tried using two `proxy_pass`and that actually works:

```
...

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
...
```

If there is not workaround, do you know any other CMS that might work like this?